# Unity Copy to clipboard on Android

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine, copy-paste

Can someone please help me with this? I saw some codes and they are really hard to understand also I am quite a beginner in Unity and C#. How to copy to clipboard text? Are there any assets maybe out there which could help?

Answer (score -1, accepted):

I am not really familliar with Android, but copying text in Unity is done like that:

```
private void CopyText(string textToCopy)
{
    TextEditor editor = new TextEditor
    {
        text = textToCopy
    };
    editor.SelectAll();
    editor.Copy();
}
```

Just call that function from whereever and you have the text in your clipboard.

But a piece of advice: maybe you want to try and get a hang of the basics in C#/Unity before you dive head first into mobile development. It's not really beginner-friendly imho.

Good luck!

Comment: Well, I consider myself as a beginner. Although I created a game on PC but I still think I am a beginner. I know the basics.

Comment: It was just a suggestion. Feel free to do whatever you want. But in my experience it is a whole lot harder to work with android based devices.

Comment: `TextEditor` is not available on the target platform. It is a class of the `UnityEditor` namespace, not `UnityEngine`

Comment: [this](https://docs.unity3d.com/2019.1/Documentation/ScriptReference/UI.TextEditor.html) docs page would suggest as much. Idk what's going on, but  the following literally works in Unity 2021.3 without the Editor namespace

`using UnityEngine;

public class Testy : MonoBehaviour
{
    void Start()
    {
        var txt = "Hello World!";
        var txtEditor = new TextEditor();
        txtEditor.text = txt;
        txtEditor.SelectAll();
        txtEditor.Copy();
    }
}`

Comment: Tbh I would highly recommend using oferei's solution as well since it's actually using the intended api and not some weird workaround

Answer (score 5):

The simple way is:

```
GUIUtility.systemCopyBuffer = "the text you want to copy";
```

I don't know if this is supported on Android.

Comment: It is working fine on my Android device. Tested with Unity 2022.2.2 and Samsung Galaxy S10e

Answer (score 1):

You should use the [**UniClipboard**](https://github.com/sanukin39/UniClipboard) asset.

Import it to your project and then just call:

```
UniClipboard.SetText("text you want to copy");
```

If you need to get the text from clipboard:

```
string text = UniClipboard.GetText();
```

Answer (score 1):

you can try the UniClipboard plugin for using an OS-dependent clipboard at Unity.

This is work in all the platforms with a simple line of code.

It has a simple interface with iOS, Android OS, and Unity Editor.

**Plugin Link :-** [UniClipboard Plugin](https://github.com/sanukin39/UniClipboard/releases/tag/v1.0.2)

Answer (score 0):

You can try something like this,

```
 void CopyToClipboard(string str) {
         TextEditor textEditor = new TextEditor();
         textEditor.text = str;
         textEditor.SelectAll();
         textEditor.Copy();
 }
 
  //Calling the method
  CopyToClipboard("Hello World");
```